# How to solve the given algorithm issue?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-ios, flutter-android, flutter-scoped-model

Basically, I am trying to fetch all comments through pagination and it's working nicely. But in case of reply, I am trying to fetch and show reply which comment has reply only and I am showing in listview builder. But problem is all reply is showing below every comment. I am leaving my code.

```
 late bool isReplyBox = false;
  final _numberOfCommentPerRequest = 5;
  late List<ReplyTile> _replyList = [];
  final PagingController<int, CommentModel> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 1);

  Future<void> _fetchAllComments(int pageKey) async {
    try {
      final response = await getAllComments(widget.classId, pageKey);

      late List<CommentModel> _commentList = [];
      response['data']['results'].forEach((element) {
        String userFName = element['creator_first_name'] ?? 'No Name';
        String userLName = element['creator_last_name'];
        String userName = "$userFName $userLName";
        String userImage = element['avatar'] ?? '';
        String commentMessage = element['comment'] ?? 'No comment';
        int commentId = element['id'] ?? 0;

        if(element['reply_comments'] != null){
          setState(() {
            isReplyBox = true;
          });
          var replyList = element['reply_comments'];
          replyList.forEach((replyData) {
            var replyMessage = replyData['comment'] ?? '';
            String creatorFName = replyData['creator_first_name'] ?? 'No Name';
            String creatorLName = replyData['creator_last_name'];
            String creatorName = "$creatorFName $creatorLName";
            String creatorImage = replyData['avatar'] ?? '';
             setState(() {
              _replyList.add(ReplyTile(
                  commentMessage: replyMessage,
                  userName: creatorName,
                  userImagePath: creatorImage));
            });
          });
        }else{
          _replyList;
          print('No reply comments');
        }

        _commentList.add(CommentModel(commentId,userImage,userName,commentMessage));

      });

      final isLastPage = _commentList.length < _numberOfCommentPerRequest;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(_commentList);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
        _pagingController.appendPage(_commentList, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error --> $e");
      _pagingController.error = e;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchAllComments(pageKey);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
      child: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => Future.sync(() => _pagingController.refresh()),
        child: PagedListView<int, CommentModel>(
          pagingController: _pagingController,
          builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<CommentModel>(
              itemBuilder: (context, item, index) =>
                  CommentTile(
                      replyList: isReplyBox == true ? replyChild() : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                      isReplyBox: isReplyBox,
                      classId: widget.classId,
                      commentId: item.commentId,
                      commentMessage: item.commentMessage,
                      userName: item.userName,
                      userImagePath: item.userImagePath)),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget replyChild() {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.8;
    return Container(
      height: _replyList.length <= 1 ? 00 : height,
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: _replyList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            return _replyList[index];
          }
      ),
    );
  }
```

Could anyone please tell how may I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.